# How to show the Android emulator without a keyboard

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm using a virtual device whose target is 2.3.1. If I run any of my android applications, the keyboard will show the right side on the emulator (see the image below). But I want to show my emulator without a keyboard. How can I do this?

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should change the resolution of Emulator when you create a new AVD. `480 X 800` can  used hide the keyboard of emulator.

Comment: See my answer below for something that work for all screen resolutions.

Answer (score 20):

The two other answers work, but they are not strictly correct. The reason they work is that the resolution suggested use a skin with no keyboard.

If you want to test your application for other screen resolutions you must do the following:

1. Add the hardware option "Keyboard support" and set it to "no".
2. Either edit the skin selected, or add a startup option "-noskin" for your emulator.

Personally I prefer the "-noskin" flag, because with no keyboard, the skin does not give me anything extra.

Comment: the `-noskin` solution is much better than this resolution hack.  This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: Infact this is the correct answer. The other two answers works because there are no skins inbuilt for those resolutions in the SDK.

Answer (score 15):

In Edit Android Virtual Device => Skins frame you can change skin from "default" (WVGA800, for example) to "Resolution" and manually write resolution of targeted device (480 x 800, for example).
Emulator will be shown without keyboard.

[image: Here you can change skin of your android emulator]

Answer (score 0):

Today I needed to hide the keyboard when starting the emulator and this worked for me.

When emulator is started, in the android keyboard options you can disable the keyboard to hide it.

[image: Emulator keyboard config]